# How to build a module and its dependencies in NodeJs

Tags: node.js, gruntjs

I've been trying to understand by reading many tutorials and documentation but I wasn't able to grasp a simple concept.

My project is quite simple so far. I did a "npm install remote-project"
and it gives me something like that

```
<my root dir>
    <node_modules>
        <remote-project>
            <node_modules>
                <remote-project-dependencies-and-more-node_modules>
```

Is there a way to build only the remote project and all its dependencies into 1 file easily? Or do I have to compile them manually using grunt?

The reason I ask is that I'm sure there is a simple way to do that using a gruntfile or an utility.

Thanks in advance.

-- Edit --

I'm trying to use "r.js" to build my module, but I'm not too sure about it. So far, I'm unable to build something using my build.js.

-- Edit 2 --

After reading a lot  about node.js/require.js/grunt.js I found out that I didn't understand the whole thing and what I was trying to do is probably not possible.  Only because nodejs modules needs to be hosted on servers. So, I'll probably have to make my own library using some of the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at WebPack (http://webpack.github.io/docs/what-is-webpack.html).

It produces a single file and can take dependencies straight from npm.

Example: https://github.com/webpack/react-starter

Comment: Seems to do exactly what I've been looking for. Thanks!